# Python 3; Writing to text files, unintentional newline (beginner)

Tags: python

The following function is a part of my future program, a library program. This particular function is supposed to fetch books from a text file, and if the user desires, "loan" them and thereby adding a string "(LOANED)" after the author of the book. The books are sorted by title first, followed by a comma and a space (, ) and then the author of the book. What I want to do is to just, simply, add a "(LOANED)" string after the author of the book in the text file. However, when I try this the (LOANED) string just ends up on a different line (one line below) from where I want it to be, and it's driving me nuts.

```
def lend_book(title):
    f = open("booksbytitle.txt", "r+")
    d={}

    #splits the registry up into a dictionary with the book title as key and the book author as value to that key 

    for i in f:
        x=i.split(",")
        a=x[0]
        b=x[1]
        d[a]=b[0:(len(b))]

    #checks if the title is in the dictionary, else skips down and quits the function
    if title in d:
        print("\n", title, "is available in the library and is written by"+d[title])
        saved_author = d[title][1:]

        while True:

            alternative=input("Do you want to lend this book? [y/n] ")
            if alternative.lower() == "y":

                print("The book is now loaned ")
                break

            elif alternative.lower() == "n":
                print("Okay, going back to main menu.. ")
                break
            else:
                print("That is not a valid choice. Type 'y' or 'n'")


        f.close()
        loaned="(LOANED)"
        f=open("booksbytitle.txt", "r+")
        z=f.readlines()
        f.seek(0)



        for i in z:

            if title not in i:
                f.write(i)

        f.write("\n" + title + ", " + saved_author + loaned)

        f.truncate()
        f.close()

    #clears the program of unintented blank lines

        fh = open("booksbytitle.txt", "r")
        lines = fh.readlines()
        fh.close()
        keep = []
        for line in lines:
            if not line.isspace():
                keep.append(line)
        fh = open("booksbytitle.txt", "w")
        fh.write("".join(keep))
        fh.close()



    else:
        print("There wasnt a book by that name found in the registry")
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, exactly, but a `\n` character appears at the end of every line.  If you don't need the surrounding whitespace just do a `line = line.strip()`.

Comment: Please use meaningful names for your variables. This `a`, `b`, `f`, `i`, `x`, `z` stuff is very hard to read.

Comment: Also, the [writetofile] tag is for the Cocoa `writeToFile:` method on `NSData` and related classes. Unless you're using PyObjC to create `NSData` objects and call methods on them, you shouldn't be using it for Python questions.

Comment: the line `d[a] = b[0:(len(b))]` can be refactored (changed) to `d[a] = b`

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell with the screwed-up formatting and the meaningless one-letter variable names, but I suspect the problem is this:

When you iterate the lines of a file, like `for i in f:`, each one ends with a newline character (`'\n'`).

When you `split(",")` each one, the last split-off string still contains that newline.

So ultimately, when you try to stick that string in the middle of a string, it's got a newline at the end, which means you end up with a newline in the middle of the string.

To fix this, use `rstrip` on each line as you read them in:

```
for i in f:
    x = i.rstrip().split(",")
```

This may mean that you're now *missing* newlines in your output to the file. You were expecting to get them for free, but now you don't. So you may have to do something like this:

```
f.write("\n" + title + ", " + saved_author + loaned + "\n")
```

However, maybe not. I notice that for some reason you're putting a `"\n"` at the *start* of every line, so this may just mean you end up with extra blank lines between each line (along with the extra blank line at the start of your file, which is inherent in using `"\n" +`).

Answer (score 1):

You could use rstrip() on the strings to remove the right spaces (newlines),
and then join over "\n" instead of the empty string.

PS: You can write a bit of this code much simpler, by the way.  For instance, you can just get the lines in the file all at once, filter out the empty ones and rstrip all at the same time, like this:

```
with open(filename, "r") as handler:
  keep = [line.rstrip() for line in handler if line]
```

(The 'with' takes care of automatically closing the file after the indented block, then there's a list comprehension, and the open file object "handler" gives you the lines when iterating over it.)